# Is it possible that staticallly typing my variables would improve script execution time?

Tags: vb.net, types

I was updating an old `.aspx.vb` script that was originally written with dynamically typed variables, like this:

```
Dim price
```

I updated them to the following format (along with some `IsDBNull` checks to compensate):

```
Dim price As String
```

After doing this to all of my variables, the script appeared to run noticeably faster. Is this a real effect of static typing, or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is part of the reason the feature (Dim var As Type) exists in VB in the first place.